# How to get the count of row from two dataframe based on some conditions

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

```
count_0 = (X_train['school_state']== 'nc' & y_train['project_is_approved'] == 0).apply(len)
```

`X_train` is one numpy array and `y_train` is another numpy array.

`X_train` has a column `school_state` which total 51 state names and one of the State name is 'nc' and `y_train` has a single column i.e `project_is_approved` which have two value which can be either 0 or 1.

I want to find out number where state name is 'nc' and `project_is_approved` is 0.

Through above code i am getting error:

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Sample y_train :  array([0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0], dtype=int64)
Sample X_train['school_state']:

47418    nc

49054    ca

35919    wi

34248    ca

15492    sd

31525    ks

36090    fl

43569    ny

9290     pa

12848    me

46189    la

33364    dc

Comment: Is there no correlation at all between the two dataframes? ie you want the sum of the number of the lines with `'nc'` in one dataframe and the number of lines with `0` in the other dataframe?

Comment: Would it be possible to provide some sample data of `X_train` and `y_train`. At the moment, it is not entirely clear to me what you aim to achieve.

Comment: @DeepSpace there is no direct correlation but both have same number of rows.

Comment: `y_train` is just an array, not a dataframe. So `y_train['project_is_approved']` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add parentheses and then you can use the method `sum`:

```
((X_train['school_state'] == 'nc') & (y_train == 0)).sum()
```